# Julia: BigFloat to byte array

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to get the binary digits of a `BigFloat` number. I thought that the easiest way to do that is to turn the number to a byte array. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766680/packing-int-and-float-to-byte-arrays-in-julia) there is a way to do that for `Float64`, but when I try the same for `BigFloat` it tells me that write does not have a method for `BigFloat`.

How can I do that with Julia?

PS. I know that there exists a method to get the binary digits as string, however this would introduce a huge overhead and I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serializing or representing BigFloats is tricky because: **a.** the BigFloat structure uses pointers, and **b.** the pointed to buffer is controlled by the GMP library which is an external library wrapped in Julia.

So as a first step, here are some functions to textually format a BigFloat in an accurate and easy to manipulate way:

```
# numbits(a) returns the number of significant digits in a BigFloat
# including digits both left and right of floating point.
# For example:
#     julia> numbits(BigFloat(3/8)
#     2
#
# This is the trickiest function since it looks slightly into
# the internal representation in GMP of BigInt data.

function numbits(a::BigFloat)
    n = a.prec
    for i=1:(a.prec>>count_ones(sizeof(Base.GMP.Limb)*8-1))
        tz = trailing_zeros(unsafe_load(a.d,i))
        n -= tz
        if tz < sizeof(Base.GMP.Limb)*8
            break
        end
    end
    return n
end
```

```
# mantissarep(a) returns a tuple with two elements. The first element is a BigInt
# holding all the significant bits of a BigFloat, and the second holds
# the exponent needed to return the floating point to its position.
# Thus, as an example, the following holds:
#     julia> a = BigFloat(1.1)
#     1.100000000000000088817841...
#
#     julia> mantissarep(a)
#     (2476979795053773, 51)
# 
#     julia> big"2476979795053773"/big"2"^51 == a
#     true
#

mantissarep(a::BigFloat) = (BigInt(a*BigFloat(2)^(numbits(a)-a.exp)),
                            numbits(a)-a.exp)
```

```
# bigfloattext(a) returns an easy textual representation of a BigFloat

function bigfloattext(bf::BigFloat)
    (a,b) = mantissarep(bf)
    return "$(sign(a)==-1 ? "-" : "")big\"$(dec(abs(a)))\"/big\"2\"^$(b)"
end
```

```
# bigfloatbintext(a) returns an easy binary textual representation a BigFloat

function bigfloatbintext(bf::BigFloat)
    (a,b) = mantissarep(bf)
    return "$(sign(a)==-1 ? "-" : "")big\"0b$(bin(abs(a)))\"/big\"2\"^0b$(bin(b))"
end
```

With these functions, one method of serializing a BigFloat is simply to write the string output of `bigfloattext`. This method is not very compact, but it will be easy to deserialize (the `parse` method for BigFloats could be used) and relatively clear. To make a more compact serialization, the bytes of `mantissarep` together with the precision field of the BigFloat could be written. This would make this answer a bit longer, so I will add if requested.

For example, writing:

```
julia> a = sin(BigFloat(π)/3)    # calculate some BigFloat
8.660254037844386467637231707529361834714026269051903140279034897259665084543988e-01

julia> println(bigfloattext(a))  # represent it as a string
big"100278890836790510567389408543623384672710501789331344711007167057270294106993"/big"2"^256

julia> # show representation is faithful
julia> big"100278890836790510567389408543623384672710501789331344711007167057270294106993"/big"2"^256 == a
true
```

Note that (in regard to other answer) writing the `d` field (=data field) of a BigFloat which is a Ptr{Limb} type is *rather useless and could possibly lead to memory corruption*.

**UPDATE**: Guided by the poster's comment below, here are another couple of functions to convert a BigFloat into a byte representation:

```
function BigFloat2Bytes(bf::BigFloat)
    bf2 = bf/big"2"^exponent(bf)-1.0
    bvec = Vector{UInt8}()
    push!(bvec,0x01)
    while bf2 != 0.0
        bf2 *= 256
        b = trunc(Int, bf2)
        push!(bvec, UInt8(b))
        bf2 -= b
    end
    return (bvec, exponent(bf))
end

function Bytes2BigFloat(bvec, e)
    bf = zero(BigInt)
    for b in bvec
        bf = bf*256 + b
    end
    return BigFloat(bf*BigFloat(2)^(e-8*length(bvec)+8))
end
```

With these we have:

```
julia> a = BigFloat(123.2323)
1.23232299999999995065991242881...e+02

julia> BigFloat2Bytes(a)
(UInt8[0x01, 0xec, 0xed, 0xe0, 0x0d, 0x1b, 0x71, 0x70], 6)

julia> Bytes2BigFloat(BigFloat2Bytes(a)...)
1.23232299999999995065991242881...e+02

julia> Bytes2BigFloat(BigFloat2Bytes(a)...) == a
true
```

Comment: Could you explain what does the first function do? I cannot really wrap my head around it.

Comment: By the way, you gave me the idea to look at the significant part of the number and taking the bytes by multiplying by 2^8 and taking the integer part each time. Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: The `numbits` function counts the number of digits in the number without regarding the floating point. That is, `12.34` would return 4 digits and so would `1.234` and `1234`. This is the number of digits in the integer which would then need to be multiplied in order to get the original BigFloat.

Comment: As for the multiplying by 2^8 idea, it should also work well. Possibly even be quick, as multiplying by 2^8 is simply changing the exponent. But getting the significant part takes a bit of computation. It boils down to do the same iterations as the `dec(...)` or `bin(...)` functions (which convert to text digits) do.

Comment: Also, the `numbits` returns the number of binary digits (not decimal).

Comment: Added functions which use the logic you suggested. See in the answer.

Comment: That is great. It is exactly what I want. Couldn't the array be initialized with its length though since the precision of bf is known?

Comment: There is **problem with BigFloat <=BigFloat(0)!** And if you fix it you have to thinking about `BigFloat2Bytes(BigFloat(Inf))` , `BigFloat2Bytes(BigFloat(Nan))` too. And probably also about `BigFloat2Bytes(BigFloat("-0"))`.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use other approach. I am not sure if I am doing it right! But maybe it is interesting. :)

Smallest overhead we could probably get by using library which is responsible for BigFloat (MPFR). So I was trying to call mpfr_sprintf (http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Formatted-Output-Functions) to get hexadecimal and binary representation of BigFloat:

```
julia> begin 
   a = " "^1000  # this could be not enough!
   f = BigFloat(123.2323)
   ccall(
      (:mpfr_sprintf, :libmpfr), 
      Int64, 
      (Cstring, Cstring, Ref{BigFloat}...),
      a, 
      "%Rb\n%Ra", 
      Ref(f), Ref(f))
   res_bin = a[1:search(a, '\n')-1]
   res_hex = a[search(a, '\n')+1:search(a, '\0')-1]
   println(res_bin)
   println(res_hex)
   println(f == BigFloat(res_hex))
   end
1.1110110011101101111000000000110100011011011100010111p+6
0x7.b3b780346dc5cp+4
true
```

Did I miss better Julia API (not ccall) to mpfr_sprintf (and other functions) somewhere around BigFloat?

**edit:** Some explanation for tst.

Sorry I think my answer is not primary for you because it is about conversion to string.

BigFloat is based on MPFR library. It has mpfr_sprintf function which could format output to string. "%Ra" is for example format string for hexadecimal output for mpfr_t type (Ref(BigFloat) is reference of this type). Julia is strong with calling c-libraries. So you could call mpfr_sprintf. I showed both binary and hexadecimal output. Output is null ended string so I needed to parse it from result. Content of res_hex value -> "0x7.b3b780346dc5cp+4" which you could use to REPL or code - it is supported hexadecimal floating point format:

```
julia> 0x7.b3b780346dc5cp+4
123.2323

julia> typeof(0x7.b3b780346dc5cp+4)
Float64
```

p+4 in it means "binary exponent" (BTW. 0x7b == 123 (from BigFloat(123.2323))

And BTW you could rewrite results from Dan's answer to hexadecimal floating point representation ->

```
# [0x01, 0xec, 0xed, 0xe0, 0x0d, 0x1b, 0x71, 0x70], 6) ->
julia> 0x1.ecede00d1b7170p+6
123.2323
```

And BTW python has hex function to return hexadecimal representation -> https://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/reference/index.html#bigfloat.BigFloat.hex

Comment: I actually have no idea what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Dan's (edited) answer looks more robust than mine, but is still a little awkward for serialization.

Just for reference, here's a quick-and-dirty answer that I use to go from `BigFloat` to `Vector{UInt8}`

```
function unsafe_serialize(p::BigFloat)
    vcat(
        reinterpret(UInt8, [p.prec]),
        reinterpret(UInt8, [p.sign]),
        reinterpret(UInt8, [p.exp]),
        reinterpret(UInt8, unsafe_wrap(Array, p.d, (4,)))
    )
end
```

and back

```
function unsafe_deserialize(::Type{BigFloat}, p::Array{UInt8})
    Base.MPFR._BigFloat(
        reinterpret(Int64, p[1:8])[1],
        reinterpret(Int32, p[9:12])[1],
        reinterpret(Int64, p[13:20])[1],
        String(p[21:52])
    )
end
```

The reason these are *dirty* is because I've hard coded the numbers and types.  In the first function, that `4` assumes your machine uses `Int64` for the C long type, and that you've stuck with the default precision (or maybe slightly reduced it).  In the second, each of those `Int*` types, and the corresponding ranges, are machine-dependent, and that final range depends on the precision.  These could probably be improved by actually using the correct sizes and types, but I'm too lazy.

I know these work with the default precision on my machine, and will likely work for most installations, but your mileage may vary (right into a segfault) if you have some non-standard machine.